# Ajax modal popup inside update panel causes flickering

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I have an ajax modal popup, which is shown on click of a button in base page.

And on click of a button in popup, Base page should be updated. Everything works perfectly fine.

But the popup flickers on click of the button in base page. Please help me to avoid this flickering effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything inside the modal popup's panel in a update panel.

Comment: If I put everything inside update panel I am getting performance issue as it takes more time